# Writing struct to child through pipe failing

Tags: c, struct, ipc, pipe

I'm attempting to fork a child and write a struct to it, but for some reason the write is failing.  Here is what I've got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    int pfd[2];
    int rv;
    if(pipe(pfd) == -1){
        printf("Pipe failed\n");
    }

    struct t{
        int count[26];
        char array[4];
    };
    struct t st;

    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        printf("Fork error\n");
    }else if(pid == 0){
        close(pfd[1]);
        rv = read(pfd[0],st,sizeof(struct t));
        printf("Read string: %d\n",rv);
    }else{
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
            st.count[i] = i;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            st.array[i] = 'A';
        }
        st.array[3] = '\0';

        close(pfd[0]);
        rv = write(pfd[1],st,sizeof(struct t));
        printf("wrote: %d",rv);
        close(pfd[1]);
    }
}
```

This has been killing me all night.  I have a suspicion that it has to do with me not fully understanding pointers to structs.  I printed sizeof(struct t) which returned 108 bytes (as expected), and I thought st was a pointer to the beginning of the struct, meaning the write command would start there and write the first 108 bytes, but clearly that's not the case.  What am I missing?

Comment: You need to pass the address of `st`. Change the parameter of the write command to `&st`.

Comment: The returned value is still -1 when replacing st with &st in the write command

Comment: This code does not compile.  Are you not noticing this and running some older version of your program?  I've certainly done that.  The `write(..., st, ...)` should yield `incompatible type for argument 2 of 'write'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `&st`. `st` is the struct itself. `&` takes a pointer off of it.

You probably need to enable (or heed) the compiler warnings. Add `-Wall` or `-Wall -Wextra` to the compile command.

---

You need to include the header file for the `read` function.

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Now you should get error messages.

Comment: I tried &st to no avail.  This code compiles, so I'm not sure what warnings to head.

Comment: Updated. Add all relevant header files.